# windows node communcates with ubuntu node failed

Tags: windows, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

a publisher node in Ubuntu send msg on topic "A",and a subscriber node in windows receive receive msg on topic "A",but it failed,and to put publisher in windows and subscriber in Ubuntu ,it succeeds.Unbuntu runs in a vitual machine,
and there is a double red circle around the windows node in rxgraph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29009/windows-node-communcates-with-ubuntu-node-failed/) by [bruce1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/1894/bruce1990/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a problem with your network configuration to me. Are you able to ping both systems from each other? Are you running your VM network as a NAT configuration?

If you are able to ping your systems in both directions you should set the [ROS_IP](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME) variable on both sides to the values you were able to ping. This should make sure, that all nodes report an address that is reachable from the other system.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0